# Append a name to array after a button is clicked and then send it to another view controller

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uikit

I'm trying to make a favourite button in my app where if the favourite image is tapped then it will append the name of the place to an array and then pass that array over to a table view inside a UIViewController. I have got it to pass an array with predetermined values inside but when I try to append names into the array and then pass it, the array in the next view controller comes out as empty.

This is in my first view controller:

```
    var fave: [String] = []

    @IBAction func faveTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        fave.append(name)
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(fave, forKey: "faves")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
```

I have this in my second view controller with the table view:

```
class nextViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var newArray: [String] = []

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if let oldArray: [String] = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "faves") as? [String] {
            newArray = oldArray
        }
        
        print(newArray)
    }
}

extension FavouritesViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return newArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let rowcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "rowcell", for: indexPath)

        rowcell.textLabel?.text = newArray[indexPath.row]

        return rowcell
    }
}
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem. It might help someone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not saving to `UserDefaults` when you append new data. The array is still empty when `viewDidLoad` executes. So do this:

```
@IBAction func faveTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    fave.append(name)
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(fave, forKey: "faves")
}
```

Comment: I've done that but now I got a new problem, the table doesn't update when I favourite a place, the only way to make the table update is if I kill the app and go back on. Secondly, it doesn't add all the places I click, only the last place that I clicked gets saved to the array.

Comment: Did you remove the code that sets `UserDefaults` from `viewDidLoad`? Also, how are you transitioning to the 2nd ViewController?

Comment: I removed it from ‘viewDidLoad’ I have a tab view controller so the favourites page is on a tab next to my first view controller tab.

Comment: Yeah thought so. You need to put the `.object(forKey: "faves")` call in the 2nd ViewController in `ViewWillAppear`. `ViewDidLoad` only gets called once since this is in a TabBarController

Comment: No. Just take the code you have in `viewDidLoad` and put it in `viewWillAppear` for the 2nd ViewController

Comment: Thanks that fixed it, but it still doesn't append more than one place. If I favourite multiple places only the place I favourited last will be passed into the next view controller through the array. How would I fix that? My append code is in the original question, first view controller.

Comment: How many elements show up when you print the array in the 2nd ViewController?

Comment: Only one, the last place that I clicked favourite on gets shown. No matter how many I click.

Comment: Just to confirm, in the `print(newArray)` not in the `TableView`?

Comment: Yeah in the `print(newArray)` only the last one I click passes through.

Comment: That absolutely should not be happening, unless it's not getting added in the original array in the first ViewController. Btw are you calling `tableView.reloadData()` in the 2nd ViewController after `.object(forKey: "faves")`?

Comment: It should be getting added as all I'm doing is appending it. Unless it resets every time for some reason. I have added `tableView.reloadData()`.

Comment: Your logic might be wrong somewhere else. Can't really see beyond what you posted. I tried something similar on my system and it works fine. You can try giving more details in the question. Maybe posting the whole class for both Controllers

Comment: I feed the name variable from one vc to another but I initialise the destination name variable as an empty string as I then assign the destination name variable to a label. Maybe it writes over the array as it's an empty string? I'm not sure at all.

Comment: Can't really understand the rest of what's going on without seeing the code

Comment: I'm having similar problems to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28925886/adding-to-swift-array-keeps-overwriting-last-object) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54630700/swift-array-append-not-appending-values-but-replacing-it). My code is written different to theirs but the main problem is still the same, instead of appending to the list it overwrites the list. I tried to do what they said in those posts but I'm not too sure how to do it.

Comment: For the 3rd time, I can't really help you without seeing more of your code. I already did something similar on my system and it worked fine

Comment: Can you show me what you did on your system and I’ll try replicate it on mine.